# C++ Printing Data on a STL list

Tags: c++, list, printing, stl

I have a Base class, and a Derived class; on the other hand I made a List class that uses the STL . Base class has a virtual function called `PrintData()`, that prints an integer that belongs to the Base class. In the Derived class; the same function `printData()` prints an integer that belong to the Derived and the other one from the Base class.

The thing is that, in the class List, I'm just getting the data from Base, no matter if I inserted a Derived instance on the list.

I need to print Derived data, that is supposed to have Base data as well.
Here is the code:

```
 #pragma once;
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
protected:
    int x;

public:
    Base(){
        x=3;
    }
    void setX(int a){
        x=a;
    }
    int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    virtual string printData(){
        stringstream f;
        f<<getX()<<endl;
        return f.str();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base{

    int a;

public:
    Derived(){
        this->Base::Base();
        a=4;
    }
    void setA(int x){
        a=x;
    }
    int getA(){
        return a;
    }
    string printData(){
        stringstream a;
        a<<getA()<<getX()<<endl;
        return a.str();
    }


};
```

And here is the List class:

```
 #pragma once;
#include "Prueba.cpp"
#include <list>

    class Lista{
        list<Base*> lp;
    public:
        Lista(){

        }

        void pushFront(Base* c){
            lp.push_front(c);
        }

        void pushBack(Base* c){
            lp.push_back(c);
        }

        void printList(){

            list<Base*>::const_iterator itr;
                for(itr=lp.begin(); itr!=lp.end(); itr++){ 
                    cout<<(*itr)->printData(); 

                }
        }

         ~Lista(){

        }
    };

    int main(){
        Derived* d=new Derived();
        Lista* l=new Lista();
        l->pushFront(d);
        l->printList();
        system("Pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

I'm just getting the Base class data, that is an integer with the value of 3.
But I'm not getting the integer from Derived that has the value of 4.

Comment: It's never necessary to call `Base::Base`, the compiler does this for you automatically. The base class constructor always comes before the derived class constructor.

Comment: This seems to work when I try it.  Are you sure you're compiling and running the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
    a<<getA()<<getX()<<endl;
```

with

```
    a<<getA()<<" "<<getX()<<endl;
```

and run it again.  I suspect that your code does print both values, only it disguises the fact.  The new line strips the disguise away, so to speak.

By the way, @MarkRansom is right.  It is not necessary to call the Base constructor explicitly.  (In fact, when I tried your code, my compiler wouldn't even allow it.)

Comment: Ufff, I know it was something silly...First it was the call of the Base constructor in the Derived(), and the the " "

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code code and it causes compile error at the `Derived` constructor. Try changing the `Derived` constructor to

```
Derived() : Base()
{
    a = 4;
}
```

I tried it and it works as it should.

**Note:** if you want both 3 and 4 to be printed you should insert at the `Lista` only `Derived*` objects.